Help with class regulation problem
I need to "transform" this block diagram to an only one block diagram:

But i never guess how to achieve de correct result, that is 
All that im able to solve is the right loop (2+(1/s)) = (2s+1)/s, and the bottom loop:
(1/s)/[1-(1/s)*(-1)]=1/(s+1)
All the upper loop, i dont know how to organize in order to achieve the correct result.
